# Why can't my rust code load a tera template?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, tera

I have a rust application (https://github.com/Riduidel/rrss2imap) which, when run on my raspberry, fails with the following error message

```
pi@raspberrypi-server:~/rrss2imap $ ./rrss2imap-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-debug run
[2019-09-02 11:46:08.847444 +02:00] INFO [rrss2imap::feed] src/feed.rs:74: Reading feed from http://tontof.net/?rss
[2019-09-02 11:46:09.203357 +02:00] INFO [rrss2imap::feed] src/feed.rs:138: Feed date is 2019-09-02 09:46:09 while previous read date is 2019-07-11 17:03:36
[2019-09-02 11:46:09.203874 +02:00] INFO [rrss2imap::feed] src/feed.rs:143: There should be new entries, parsing HTML content
[2019-09-02 11:46:09.211703 +02:00] INFO [rrss2imap::feed] src/feed.rs:74: Reading feed from https://www.brothers-brick.com/feed/
[2019-09-02 11:46:10.897497 +02:00] INFO [rrss2imap::feed] src/feed.rs:138: Feed date is 2019-09-02 02:00:37 while previous read date is 2019-07-11 14:40:44
[2019-09-02 11:46:10.898026 +02:00] INFO [rrss2imap::feed] src/feed.rs:143: There should be new entries, parsing HTML content
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error(Msg("Template \'message.html\' not found"), State { next_error: None, backtrace: InternalBacktrace { backtrace: None } })', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

What is really weird is that when I run the same code from `cargo run` it works like a charm.

So what is going wrong ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program can't find the template file.

You have two options:

- Ship the templates directory together with the binary and put them on the server, in the location where the binary loads the templates from.
- Statically include your templates into your binary with [include_str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html), and then load them with [Tera::add_raw_template](https://docs.rs/tera/1.0.0-beta.14/tera/struct.Tera.html#method.add_raw_template).

PS: you can also embed whole directories into your app with crates like [include_dir](https://github.com/Michael-F-Bryan/include_dir).

Comment: Well, I was thinking including other dirs could be done at cargo level using `include` directive, isn't it possible ? (or does it imply some oddities I didn't understood) ?

Comment: That only specifies what files get included in the archive that gets built when you publish the crate, not the binary.